# Visual Studio Live Server never uses 127.0.0.1, instead uses my public address

Tags: visual-studio-code, localhost, liveserver

When I try to launch live server of my index.html, they are always launched on my public IP address +  route of file.
I try to change the configuration of `settings.json` of live server extension, but always are launched in my public IPV4 address.

How can I launch my applications on localhost?

---

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Flatland Monokai",
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
"liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true,
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters": {
    " ": true
},
"liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [

    ".vscode/**",
    "**/*.scss",
    "**/*.sass",
    "**/*.ts"
],
"settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
    "ritwickdey.liveserver"
],
"liveServer.settings.host": "localhost",
"editor.linkedEditing": true,
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""
```

}

Comment: 127.0.0.1 already is an ipv4 address. 

Is live server launching on your *public* IPV4 address? Eg the problem in that instead of using 127.0.0.1, live server is running on (eg) 1.2.3.4?

Comment: Yes, when i try to launch LIVE SERVER on vscode of my project they are always launching on my ip 1.2.3.4 (for example). For solve that i need manually put, 127.0.0.1 instead of the 1.2.3.4

Comment: OK that makes sense - I've edited the question to state your '**public** IPv4 address' - someone should help you. You should also add what you tried editing in `settings.json`. Welcome to StackOverflow!